# SharePoint 2013 _vti_bin/usergroup.asmx 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, spservices

I am getting this ERROR: _vti_bin/usergroup.asmx 500 (Internal Server Error) when i try to get User Information.

Can anyone see whats wrong with the code:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.12.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetUserInfo",
            async: false,
            userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).find("User").each(function() {
                    curUserId = $(this).attr("ID");
                    curUserName = $(this).attr("Name");
                    curFullUserName = $(this).attr("ID") + ";#" + $(this).attr("Name");
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar when working with an O365 tenant client (not sure what your environment looks like).  When I logged in as my own account that had delegated administration with their environment, I could not access the indicated URL.  However, when I logged in as Cloud account for their environment - it worked as expected.